# WebLogic Portal VCR IllegalMonitorStateException connection to JSR-170 Repository

Tags: weblogic, portal, jackrabbit

We have recently upgraded from WebLogic Portal 9.2.3 to 10.3.5. We have a JackRabbit repository connected through the Day Software JSR-170 VCR-JCR provider. This has all worked perfectly fine on 9.2.3, but on 10.3.5 we are getting a IllegalMonitorStateException when we try to retrieve content. We have out own facade on top of JackRabbit, that implements the JCR-170. Here is the debug out from the server:

```
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.initializeSessionState():1215] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2b70161: (re)initializing all repo sessions for username: <WLS Kernel>
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.initializeSessionState():1215] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2bf2311: (re)initializing all repo sessions for username: <WLS Kernel>
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.initializeSessionState():1215] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2fa5952: (re)initializing all repo sessions for username: <anonymous>
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.ensureConnectedToRepository():801] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2fa5952: no session found for repoName=indhold; need to connect
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.ensureConnectedToRepository():821] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2fa5952: connect write lock acquired for repoName=indhold
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.connectToRepository():875] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2fa5952: connecting to repositoryName= indhold
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.getRepositoryClass():1503] invoking Class.forName(repoClassName)
[com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.getRepository():1403] com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate@2fa5952: Ticket authentication error for: indhold java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:363)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1317)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:745)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.getRepositoryClass(RepositoryManagerDelegate.java:1537)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.getRepository(RepositoryManagerDelegate.java:1327)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.connectToRepository(RepositoryManagerDelegate.java:893)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.ensureConnectedToRepository(RepositoryManagerDelegate.java:832)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryManagerDelegate.connect(RepositoryManagerDelegate.java:1160)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.delegate.RepositoryHelper.checkCapability(RepositoryHelper.java:759)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.CapabilityManagerImpl.checkRepositoryCapability(CapabilityManagerImpl.java:57)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.ManagerImplCapabilityHelper.checkCapability(ManagerImplCapabilityHelper.java:80)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.ManagerImplCapabilityHelper.verifyCapability(ManagerImplCapabilityHelper.java:54)
at com.bea.content.federated.internal.NodeManagerImpl.getNode(NodeManagerImpl.java:432)
at dk.skat.portal.front.helper.ContentHelper.getNode(ContentHelper.java:1591)
```

It seems that authenticationn fails, but if I try to set a break-point in the login methods in the repository (our Facade, which doesn't do any authentication challenge, but just wraps JackRabbit, and logs in the same user - "default" - for all access), we are never getting called. Setting the username and password on the Manage Repositories page, doesn't seem to have any effect.
If I on the other hand go to Portal Administration Console, and try to manage or browse the repository, everything works fine, and the login methods are actually called, and the server connects fine to the repository.
This seems very strange. In cetain cases (that happens to happen randomly, we can get the server to all of a sudden get to the repository, but on restart of the server, it is again back to failing).

I've tried to set username/password for the repository to the weblogic user, but that doesn't seem to have any effect, I still get the error.
Furthermore when I've been into the PAC, and logs out, closes the browser, reopen the browser or a completely different browser, the entering of PAC seems to activate the repository to become online (though this is not stable or desired).

Please advice, if there is a bug in WebLogic (it seems it tries to unlock() the ReadLock too many times, resulting in the mentioned exception - should it at all fail on that exception??, Should the lock-count be checked before unlocking?), or if w are doing anything wrong? I can read that there is a known bug in the eclipse tooling for 10.3.5 about exactly this error.

Furthermore, we didn't seem to have any trouble in 9.2.3, what changed in 10.3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same issue, found solution here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10984645

In short, it is a product bug, request following patch from Oracle:

```
WLP Version: 10.3.5
Patch Name/Patch Number/Bug Number: 14377862
Smart Update Patch ID: HPV8
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that out, after I decompiled the code and fixed the bug myself. The patch is on now.